# AngularJS bind element height

Tags: angularjs, bind

How can I bind an element's height in AngularJS? So that when element A changes height, element B will change as well instantly.

Comment: Is element B inside A? If so, this can be achieved with proper CSS code. Otherwise, you might want to use events. Your question seems too abstract.

Comment: @Cracker It can be element B inside A. But if element B is `position: fixed;`. How can I have element A to be same height as element B?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to achieve the result you want is to observer whether the element A's height has changed and then update the element B's height. [Here's a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xO5aeoX0xqfitiCIoDGQ). I have created a directive that broadcasts an event if the height of the element that it is attached to has changed. The other element listens to that event and updates its height.
However, you should be aware of the fact that using `$element` in controllers is *not* recommended, you might want to use a directive.